# Microsoft Office 2013 and SPSS on ubuntu

Tags: windows

I have just installed ubuntu on my laptop and I was wondering whether Office 2013 and SPSS 22 will also work on ubuntu. If you have any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Forums Julius!

SPSS 22 will run on Linux, as it is available for Linux.
Read the 'Linux' article on [their website](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/downloads/trial-installation.html) for installation.

With Microsoft office it is a bit harder, since it is not available for Linux and therefore, theoretically will not work.
However, using an emulator, you can use it.
[HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/171565/how-to-install-microsoft-office-on-linux/) Has a very good article on how to do it, but you must have a pretty good computer for it.
Because of Ubuntu apparently working for you i think your computer should be good enough, but just to be sure please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/673576/edit/848a8171-d94a-4f9d-948b-5b95ce04de86) your answer and post your hardware specifications.

Comment: Have you really succeeded installing office 2013 by simply executing the installer in Wine, as the link you posted suggests??